# Cortar palavra depois da virgula

Tags: php

Tenho um código para cortar as palavras depois da vírgula. Mas tem como eu saber quantas string irão ser geradas pelo cortador ? Pois a pessoa pode colocar 5 palavras, como também pode colocar 10 de uma só vez.

```
$str  = "valor1,valor2,valor3";
$corta = explode(",", $str);
echo $corta[0];
echo $corta[1];
```

Comment: Para isso você deveria usar um `loop` que vai imprimir o resultado N vezes de acordo com o tamanho do seu array

Comment: Você pode usar o `count` para saber quantos elementos tem no array, ou seja, quantas palavras: `count($corta)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [count](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.count.php), para contar os elementos do array, e depois pode fazer um loop a seu gosto

```
<?php
$str   =  "valor1,valor2,valor3";
$corta  =  explode(",", $str);
for($i=0 ; $i  < count($corta); $i++)
{
    echo  $corta[$i]."\n";
}
?>
```

[Exemplo](https://ideone.com/U242RN)

Comment: Como posso salvar cada corte separadamente no banco de dados ? Eu tentei o seguinte, mas não deu certo ( salvou apenas a ultima string ):

$str   =  "$a_palavra";
$corta  =  explode(",", $str);
for($i=0 ; $i  < count($corta); $i++)
{
    $res_word =  $corta[$i];
    echo "$res_word";
}


   $insert_word = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO filtro_word (palavra) VALUES ('$res_word')");

Comment: @CodegTechSistemas você deve dar `insert` dentro do seu `loop`, concorda que é dentro do seu `loop` em que você tem acesso aos `cortes` separadamente? Acho que é valido dar uma estudada em `loops` como `for`, `while`, etc.

Comment: Você pode abrir uma nova questão, confira [help] para ver a melhor forma de fazer. A dica do amigo é válida.